# Documentation for python-gnomeapplet and friends

Tags: python, pygtk, gnome

I'm attempting to write a Gnome applet using Python and pygtk. Sadly all sources of information that I have been able to find are from 2004 or older, and while the general structures presented are still valid, most of the particulars are out-of-date. Even the example applets I've found through web searches no longer work.

Does anyone know where I can find good, up-to-date documentation and information on how to create gnome panel applets in Python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a step-by-step tutorial, which might be the most up-to-date:

http://www.znasibov.info/blog/post/gnome-applet-with-python-part-1.html

Also check out the various applets listed in Gnome projects.

Comment: That's the one good article I've found as well. With a combination of that, this (http://saravananthirumuruganathan.wordpress.com/2010/01/15/creating-gnome-panel-applets-in-python/) and looking through existing applets, I've managed to get it working.